# gdb core dump can not see any symbols after "sudo apt-get install libc6-dbg"

Tags: c++, linux, ubuntu, gdb, libc

I am trying to debug a program in Ubuntu 12.04(x86_64) LTS with core dump file. At the beginning, the "bt" command is ok, just like below

```
(gdb) bt
#0  0x00007f3b38e3f425 in raise () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
#1  0x00007f3b38e42b8b in abort () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
#2  0x00007f3b38e7d39e in ?? () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
#3  0x00007f3b38e87b96 in ?? () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
#4  0x00007f3b3947dff6 in std::string::assign(std::string const&) () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6
#5  0x000000000041cf5a in operator= (__str=..., this=<optimized out>) at /usr/include/c++/4.6/bits/basic_string.h:542
```

I want to see the  symbol in libc.so.6 , so I install  libc6-dbg using

```
sudo apt-get install libc6-dbg
```

but after install

```
libc6-dbg
```

I get all the thing wrong , showing in the below:

```
(gdb) bt
#0  0x00007f3b38e3f425 in ?? () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
#1  0x00007f3b38e42b8b in ?? () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
#2  0x0000000000000003 in ?? ()
#3  0x00007fffca496804 in ?? ()
#4  0x000000000000000c in ?? ()
#5  0x00007f3b38f84eab in ?? () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
#6  0x0000000000000002 in ?? ()
#7  0x0000000000000020 in ?? ()
#8  0x0000000000000000 in ?? ()
```

I try to remvoe lib6c-dbg with

```
sudo apt-get remove libc6-dbg
```

but it cant make any effect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I get all the thing wrong , showing in the below:

What *probably* happened is that `apt-get install libc6-dbg` *also* updated already installed `libc6`, and the currently installed `libc.so.6` no longer matches the one that was used when the `core` file was generated.

For GDB analysis, you need an *exact* matching copy as what was used at runtime.

So you'll need to re-install the *old* version of `libc6` (look in `/var/log/apt/history.log` to find out what it was), and a *matching* version of `libc6-dbg`.

**Update:**

> It seems that the command apt-get install libc6-dbg get the libraries with version 2.15-0ubuntu10.12

Just as I guessed could be the case.

> How can I recover it to the version in 2.15-0ubuntu10.4

This is really a sysadmin question, but [here is an answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/92021) I found on Google ;-)

```
sudo apt-get install libc6=2.15-0ubuntu10.4 libc6-dbg=2.15-0ubuntu10.4
```

should do the trick.

Comment: yes, the `libc.so.6` and  `libstdc++.so.6` are different . I copy these two files from another computer  and use `set solib-absolute-prefix` in GDB. All things seem ok. But how can I get these two libraries ( `libc.so.6` and  `libstdc++.so.6`) restore to my computer? Just replace them simply? If I just replace these two files directly, will the programs using these two libraries break down?

Comment: @user5232088 In your question, you didn't mention *anything* about another computer, or copying. Why don't you edit it to tell the *whole* story (details matter here). And no, copying libc.so.6 from another computer is a *really bad idea* and is almost guaranteed to render your system unbootable. Don't do that.

Comment: I have 2 computers, they are running the exact same system(Ubuntu 12.04(x86_64) . I use one of them to `sudo apt-get install libc6-dbg` and get the question I asked.When I look in /var/log/apt/history.log, I just find stuff about libc6-dbg `Start-Date: 2015-08-17  00:21:21
Commandline: apt-get install libc6-dbg
Install: libc6-dbg:amd64 (2.15-0ubuntu10.12)
End-Date: 2015-08-17  00:21:23`. So I copy the libraries from another computer and use it in GDB, and it gets the right answer.

Comment: It seems that the command `apt-get install libc6-dbg` get the libraries with version 2.15-0ubuntu10.12 (`Install: libc6-dbg:amd64 (2.15-0ubuntu10.12`)) to the computer.  I found the libc6 version in another computer is 2.15-0ubuntu10.4. How can I recover it to the version  2.15-0ubuntu10.4?Thanks you very much.

Comment: Thanks you very much. But when I use `sudo apt-get install libc6=2.15-0ubuntu10.4 libc6-dbg=2.15-0ubuntu10.4`. I get something wrong  `Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Version '2.15-0ubuntu10.4' for 'libc6' was not found` . I found the package in `https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/precise/amd64/libc6/2.15-0ubuntu10.4`. Can i use this package? Will it replace the version in my computer or it will be 2 versions of libc6 in my computer?

Comment: @user5232088 Yes, downloading http://launchpadlibrarian.net/129756722/libc6_2.15-0ubuntu10.4_amd64.deb and using `dpkg -i ibc6_2.15-0ubuntu10.4_amd64.deb` will do the trick and downgrade your libc6 version to the one you want. You could also grab http://launchpadlibrarian.net/129756732/libc6-dbg_2.15-0ubuntu10.4_amd64.deb while you are at it.

Answer (score 1):

`remove` only removes the binaries but not the configuration and data files, what you might need is `purge`. `sudo apt-get purge libc6-dbg` should do the trick.

Comment: I also use `purpge`, but it also make no sense. But thank you,too